# cq5 access component properties

Tags: extjs, aem

created a component under `/apps/project` folder
comp1 with properties `jcr:title`, `jcr: description` etc.

All comp1 properties are stored at

```
/apps/project/components/common/comp1
```

**I would like to access above component properties when this component drag and drop onto a page**

Now the component is drag and drop onto a page.
when I do currentNode.getPath - `/content/project/en/page1/jcr:content/comp1`

Not sure, how I could access the path 
`/apps/project/components/common/comp1` and read properties such as `jcr:title`, `jcr:description`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`jcr:title`, `jcr:description` properties are copied from `/apps/project/components/common/comp1` to component when you dragged component to yours page.

So, you are able to acces this porperties using following code:

```
String title = currentNode.getProperty("jcr:title");
String description = currentNode.getProperty("jcr:description");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use AEM6 in the JSP you can use properties.propertyname, also if you want to get a page property you can use pageProperties.propertyname